# Artificial pageview pushed to Analytics is changing PPC traffic source

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-analytics

So basically, we are having issues with a website (https://thesoundshop.com) in which the PPC traffic source (it only seems to be PPC traffic that is affected) is being changed by the pageview that we are pushing through to analtics.

The website runs on Ajax so we have to use Javascript to emulate pageviews through to Analytics whenever a link is clicked on the website. We are not using Google Tag Manager to implement the analytics or javascript because of this so we are using the gtag method exactly as Google's documentation recommends:

gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID');

I have tested this by visiting the website through a PPC ad and watching the real-time reports in Analytics. The first page load attributes the correct source to the traffic (cpc) as expected but then when I click on a link to go to a different page, the traffic source changes to Google Organic search. I then complete an action that I know will trigger an event or a goal and then when this appears in the Goal Reports, it attributes the goal as organic, too.

We know that this has to be down to the Javascript pageview that is being pushed to analytics to simulate that a new page has loaded but we can't work out why it would be changing the traffic source. The gtags are implemented exactly as Google recommends; just wondering if anyone else has had this problem and if so, how did they go about fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and after some more research found the problem along with the solution, [thanks to Simo](https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/fix-rogue-referral-problem-single-page-sites).

Basically, you need to manually set the document.referrer of the first session to make sure it persists and does not get over-written half way through the session. It's a known issue with GTM and single page applications.